# Compiling and linking position independent code (PIC) for ARM M4

Tags: c, arm, position, pic, bootloader

I'm working on making a bootloader and giving it the ability to update itself. This process involves copying the binary to a new location, jumping to it, and using it to flash the new bootloader in the original location. This is all being developed for an M4 processor in Eclipse, using the ARM GCC toolchain.

To do this, I've gathered that I need to compile as Position Independent Code (PIC).

I've searched around and found this excellent article, so when I added "-fPIC" to the ARM GCC compiler call I expected to see linker errors about GOT and PLT being missing
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/

In my linker script, I added these location to the .data section as follows:

```
.data : AT(__DATA_ROM)
{
. = ALIGN(4);
__DATA_RAM = .;
__data_start__ = .; /* Create a global symbol at data start. */
*(.got*) /* .got and .plt for position independent code */
*(.data) /* .data sections */
*(.data*) /* .data* sections */
KEEP(*(.jcr*))
. = ALIGN(4);
__data_end__ = .; /* Define a global symbol at data end. */
} > m_data
```

However, this code fails to copy-up from ROM to RAM.

My next thought was that perhaps my linker needed to be aware it was linking a PIC executable. To find out, I added "--pic-executable" to the LD linker script call. However, the linker now generated sections for "interp", "dyn", "rel.dyn" and "hash". I tried throwing these into the data section as well, but got the following errors:

> gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:
> could not find output section .hash
>
> gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe:
> final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output

I assume this means the compiler didn't actually fill the ".hash" section with anything, so the link failed.

Am I going about this correctly? Is there anything else I need to add to get the compiler to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not the only solution and is somewhat of a painful way to do it.  just copy and jump to run the bootloader from ram.

Comment: have you asked this question before as a different user, this was already covered, seems very familiar to a prior question trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @old_timer I agree, but copying to another location and running does not work if the program was compiled for a static location. Inevitably, the compiler decides to throw in a BLX [address from original location] and the program crashes if there's nothing there. It must be compiled to be position independent, or there needs to be a compiler instruction I am not aware of.

No, I have not asked this question before.

Comment: of course it works, just like any other bootloader, you link it for the location where it will run, not for the location where it wont be running.

Comment: @old_timer This bootloader normally resides at (for example) 0x10000, as its primary job is to flash firmware. It needs to be compiled to run at 0x10000 *or ideally* anywhere else. I would greatly appreciate help in compiling it to run in other locations........

Comment: ram is at 0x20000000 build it for that address, then copy it there and jump to it...

Comment: or if you want the bootloader to also allow ram based programs to be run then perhaps 0x200XX000 leaving at least some room for a ram based program to be loaded and run.  All depends initially on what your design goals are for the bootloader.

Comment: normally on a cortex-m4 you build for 0x00000000, some vendors have alternate addresses for user flash that in the right boot mode is mirrored in part at 0x00000000, 0x08000000 from one vendor for example and 0x01000000 for another.

Comment: you also need to design your scheme for how you want to boot the application from flash vs boot the bootloader, is it going to be a strap pin or hit a key on the uart or other?   Are you going to see if an application is in place or simply jump to it if the bootloader is not selected?  Check for non 0xFFs or have some checksum/crc of some or part of the image, other?   Have you confirmed the part doesnt already have a bootloader, if NXP or ST you dont really need to bother if atmel or infineon or ti, then maybe...

Comment: write a line or two of asm and a few lines of C, build and link (for any address, ideally non-zero) using PIC and see what the toolchain does, gnu it is pretty easy to see what is going on and what is required to use PIC.  Should be a similar experience with other toolchains, but at the end of the day it is very much toolchain dependent as to how to deal with PIC if you still feel you want to put that effort in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, neither I nor NXP's technical support team were able to get their S32DS IDE to compile truly position independent code.

To this day, we have two bootloaders - one compiled for location A, the other is an intermediate for location B. Both of which are required for an update.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I researched extensively Cortex-M4 bootloading a PIC firmware image.

There are couple of things needed:

A very simple bootloader. It only needs to read 2 4-byte words from the flash location of the firmware image. First is stack pointer address and second is Reset_Handler address. Bootloader needs to jump to Reset_Handler. But as the firmware is relocated further in the flash, the Reset_Handler is actually a bit further. See this picture for clarification:

[image]

So, bootloader adds the correct offset before jumping to Reset_Handler of the firmware image. No other patching is done, but bootloader (in my solution at least) stores location and offset of the firmware image, calculates checksum and passes this information in registers for the firmware image to use.

Then we need modifications in firmware linker file to force the ISR vector table in the beginning of RAM. For Cortex-M4 and VTOR (Vector Offset Table Register) the ISR vector table needs to be aligned to 512 boundary. In the beginning of RAM it is there naturally. In linker script we also dedicate a position in RAM for Global Offset Table (GOT) for easier manipulation. Address ranges should be exported via linker script symbols also.

We need also C compiler options. Basically these:

-fpic

-mpic-register=r9

-msingle-pic-base

-mno-pic-data-is-text-relative

They go to C compiler only! This creates the Global Offset Table (GOT) accounting.

Finally we need dedicated and tedious assembly bootstrap routines in the firmware image project. These routines perform the normal startup task of setting up the C runtime environment, but they additionally also go and read ISR and GOT from flash and copy them to RAM. In RAM, the addresses of those tables pointing to flash are offsetted by the amount the firmware image is running apart from bootloader. Example pictures:

[image]
[image]

I spent last 6 months researching this subject and I have written an in-depth article about it here:

https://techblog.paalijarvi.fi/2022/01/16/portable-position-independent-code-pic-bootloader-and-firmware-for-arm-cortex-m0-and-cortex-m4/

By providing the link I hope I can contribute to StackOverflow which I used as a starting point for my research. I hope this helps some people in learning the intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

Booting a code and relocating involves many careful steps and initialization of configuration of RAM, SPI and other necessary peripherals.

I know U-Boot does the sequence you are trying to achieve. So a better starting is to walk through u-boot [documentation](https://www.denx.de/wiki/pub/U-Boot/SummitELCE2015/U-Boot_startup_sequence.pdf) and sources in, machine specific folders for the processor or board of interest.

Comment: In this implementation, the old bootloader in the new location is doing a full copy-up and system init. Initialization of peripherals is not the issue.

If I compile the bootloader to run at the new address, it works as designed. Thus, I *just* need to make the program address-independent

Answer (score 0):

TI does this with the Tivaware bootloader.  You can do it with linker gnu ld trickery:

```
.text 0x20000000 : AT (0x00000000)
{
_text = .;
KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
*(.text*)
*(.rodata*)
_etext = .;
}
```

Startup code that copies this code from Flash at 0x0 to SRAM at 0x2000_0000 is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Isn't this just a copy-up so the segment can run from a specific SRAM location? I greatly appreciate the time to respond, but this question was more about how to make it totally position independent - i.e. to let the same binary run from 0x30000000 (or wherever) if moved there (this particular boot-loader is too big for the RAM segment)

Comment: From what I can tell, position-independent code is not well supported, and you will need external support - something has to tell the PIC where things are, perhaps by configuring a register.      Hence the reason for the TI approach above - the bootloader always runs out of SRAM, so it can update itself or rather update the pre-copy version of itself.